# Loading problems when sharing a link on a site with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I' ve created a website that uses Vue as front-end framwork and the CMS CosmisJS to manage the content. My site uses, among other things, Vue Router, Vuex and Vue Meta and is hosted on Netlify.

My site works fine, you can navigate between the different routes and the information loads without problems, however, when I share a link with a route, for example, http://example.com/route, the page simply doesn't load and shows me a Netlify error that says "Page Not Found" even though the route exists and can be visited if you navigate from the root route.

I can't figure out where the problem is. I thought it might be an error related to load times with API calls or some error in my Vue Router configuration, but I have made changes and the problem still persists.

Any idea what it could be?

Here is a simplified version of my Vue Router.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import CentroEstudios from "../views/CentroEstudios.vue";
import Nosotras from "../views/Nosotras.vue";
import Index from "../views/Index.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Index",
    component: Index,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
  },
  {
    path: "/centro-de-estudios",
    name: "Centro de Estudios",
    component: CentroEstudios,
  },
  {
    path: "/nosotras",
    name: "Nosotras",
    component: Nosotras,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of using **history** mode on the router.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly.

You need to configure Netlify to be compatible with history mode:
https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps

Here is another relevant post on the netlify support forum:
https://answers.netlify.com/t/vue-app-not-routing-correctly-when-deployed/6363

Or, if it's ok for the purposes of the website you're making, you can also just use the default hash mode and then you do not have this issue but you will have a hash before in all the URL paths.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the solution to my problem! I had been at it for days without finding the solution.